# Selenium throws "result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response"exception after starting ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

selenium-java : below error is coming

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response
  (Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.106)
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [be2be43330ab6189b2d7de1140d52848, getCurrentUrl {}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 119.0.6045.106, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 118.0.5993.70 (e52f33f30b91..., userDataDir: C:\Users\lahiruh\AppData\Lo...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:60649}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:60649/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 119.0.6045.106, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: be2be43330ab6189b2d7de1140d52848
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:675)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:679)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getCurrentUrl(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)
    at com.alaqahtml5.qa.pages.BasePageObject.getCurrentUrl(BasePageObject.java:57)
    at com.alaqahtml5.qa.loginpagetests.LogInTestAll.logInTestsAll(LogInTestAll.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:481)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)'''
```

Comment: Can you share reproducible example of code?

Comment: this issue was fixed when upgrading the driver chrome driver version to :  119.0.6045.105, chrome Version 119.0.6045.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 5):

You have this issue, because **Chrome** version `119.0.6045.106` doesn't match with **Chrome driver** version `118.0.5993.70`.

Seemed like for some reason correct error message that versions are mismatched hasn't shown this time, and end users got not explanative `result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response`

To fix issue you should:

1. Upgrade Chrome driver to latest [stable version](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) `119.0.6045.105`
2. Upgrade Selenium version to `4.14.1` OR
3. Upgrade Selenium version to `4.15.0`

[Reference to issue in Selenium Github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13081)