# unknown error: result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When running my testcase, I get this unknown error:

```
result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response
```

I tried to find the correct driver without changing my browser version. My browser version is 119 and I took the same for the driver.

Comment: This error may occur when the ChromeDriver version is not compatible with the Chrome browser version, or when the JSON. please recheck and add fresh driver once again and configure once again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium throws "result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response"exception after starting ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424990/selenium-throws-result-webdrivervalue-value-list-is-missing-or-empty-in-runtime)

Comment: Could you please [edit] the testcase and the full error, including traceback, into your question? Without them, it might be hard to tell what exactly caused the error. Be sure to add a [mcve], containing the least possible code that raises your error.

Answer (score 11):

I think this is a generic message that the session cannot be created, previously SessionNotCreated exception [How to address SessionNotCreatedException with latest chromedriver.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75140505/how-to-address-sessionnotcreatedexception-with-latest-chromedriver-exe).
I updated both the ChromeDriver and the Chrome on the machine with the latest versions available (119) and the issue is gone. Before the update I had Selenium.Webdriver.Chromedriver\119.0.6045.10500 and chrome version 118.

Selenium team has closed the connected issue.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13081

Comment: Seems to affect Edge as well. After updating the browser to version 119.0.2151.44 I needed to install a new Microsoft Edge WebDriver too.

Comment: For me the issue was when we called driver.Title, caused this exception when we had Chrome 119 and Chromedriver 118.  Upgrading too 119 driver fixed it, but breaks our understanding that 1 version back was always acceptable with the driver.

Answer (score 4):

I'm still unsure of the issue, it's currently only happening in my Edge browser on version 119 due to previous usage. I have changed from EdgeDriver **to Chrome/ChromeDriver**, this might initalize new sessions or builds what helps:

- Chrome v119
- Selenium.WebDriver v4.12.4
- WebDriverManager for automatic download of ChromeDriver

**update**

I've updated my WebDriverManager to download the matching driver for v119 in Edge - now the problem is fixed:

```
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new EdgeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);
```

Comment: Edge works now following recent update

Answer (score 2):

**I had the same problem**

```
src.exception.exceptions.ScraperException: Message: unknown error: result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response
```

my tools were:

```
Google Chrome version: 119.0.6045.105
Chromedriver version: 118.0.5993.70

Chip: Apple M1
```

The solution for this was:

I had to upgrade `Chromedriver version` to `119.0.6045.105`(Current Stable Version)

Comment: Updating my Chrome Driver to the latest version fixed it for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem. I have updated the chromedriver version: 119.0.6045.105. It was solved!

Answer (score 1):

Your chromedriver was not compatible with your actual browser. You can update your chromedriver.exe from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads , and make sure you have the same chromedriver and actual browser version.

If you are using the chromedriver 115 or newer, you can update it from "Chrome for Testing Availability" page.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Webdriver manager Nuget packet to load the latest driver. When I started debugging I found out that Webdriver Manager loaded Edge Driver 118 version instead of 119 (so the latest version at the moment detected wrong with the manager), and I changed browserVersion Strategy from Latest to MatchingBrowser. And the problem was solved.

string browserVersion = VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser;

Answer (score 0):

For those who are seeing this issue on Edge for a previously working code, it started happening with the release of MS Edge browser on 119.0.2151.44 on Nov 2, 2023. One of the easy fixes is update the edge driver to be on the same version. It worked for me.