# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am trying to fetch a column from a table in a web element.

Error message after running a python selenium script.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response
(Session info: MicrosoftEdge=119.0.2151.72)
tacktrace:
GetHandleVerifier [0x00E5C3B3+228579]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::time_ticks_t::time_ticks_t [0x00D3DE41+403697]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00B4CCB2+3906]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00B4FD75+16389]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00B51068+21240]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00B510F0+21376]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::GUID_t::GUID_t [0x00B7D9A8+104248]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::GUID_t::GUID_t [0x00B7DD5F+105199]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::GUID_t::GUID_t [0x00BA4E82+265234]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::GUID_t::GUID_t [0x00B92B54+190692]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::GUID_t::GUID_t [0x00B77343+78035]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::GUID_t::GUID_t [0x00BA37C0+259408]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::GUID_t::GUID_t [0x00B92866+189942]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::GUID_t::GUID_t [0x00B7664B+74715]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::GUID_t::GUID_t [0x00B75DFB+72587]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::GUID_t::GUID_t [0x00B76D4D+76509]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00F20092+1030594]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::FromJSON [0x00FEEF14+129108]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::FromJSON [0x00FEE8A5+127461]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::FromJSON [0x00FE4D5A+87706]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::FromJSON [0x00FEF919+131673]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::time_ticks_t::time_ticks_t [0x00D52313+486851]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::time_ticks_t::time_ticks_t [0x00D479B8+443496]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::time_ticks_t::time_ticks_t [0x00D47B21+443857]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::time_ticks_t::time_ticks_t [0x00D309F4+349348]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75316839+25]
RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x770B906F+1215]
RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x770B903D+1165]
```

I am trying to fetch a column from a table in a web element. (using edge driver)

Comment: user22762241 please, update your question with your current code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium throws "result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response"exception after starting ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424990/selenium-throws-result-webdrivervalue-value-list-is-missing-or-empty-in-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a recent issue:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13081

> Make sure your driver and browser versions match and are the latest versions

I guess both the `Chromedriver` and `Google Chrome` versions be 119+;

`Chromedriver version 119.0.6045.105` should be good for now.

---

Microsoft Edge users are also facing this issue:

If your MS Edge browser is `119.0.2151.44`

then

**Update the Edge driver to be on the same version**

Comment: I am using Microsoft Edge Driver. Latest Version MicrosoftEdge=119.0.2151.72. But still the error is same,

Comment: What is your `driver` version ?